Citing in RevTex4.2
How can I automatically add the brackets [  ] around my citation number with \onlinecite in RevTex4.2? I was trying to use \cite with biblatex package but it couldn't work with RevTex4.2.
I tried to refer to the RevTex4.2 template at Overleaf and CTAN (for APS) but they were either using \cite with \bibitem or ~[\onlinecite].
I do not want to add the brackets [] manually around my citations with \onlinecite, so is there any way to add them automatically?

The whole point of the \onlinecite macro is to just print the number, without formatting. You want to use \cite, which will add the appropriate brackets (if that is the citation style). As you have noticed, RevTeX sadly does not support biblatex, you need to use BibTeX. Citing works mostly the same, though.
